# C++Testing and Application with Menu

Tags: c++, testing, visual-studio-2012

I am looking to test an Application, which has a multiple tear menu system - which you can navigate through. Is there a way that I can automate the testing of this application using say a Python script ? or a bolt on for Visual Studio?

Edit: The whole program works in the Console - with the application expecting a `std::cin` for most of the inputs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot of this kind of thing with a high-end tool like Rational Test, but you will pay mega-bux for the privilege.

On Windows you can send Windows messages to the appropriate Window.  It involves a bit of fiddling to find the Window handle, but it isn't *too* hard.  Not sure if this is possible on *nix, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Another option is to "instrument" your program.  Listen on a socket for "commands" and execute them.  You need to be careful that you don't introduce a security hole.  As long as you only accept local sockets and don't give any extra privilege to socket commands (as opposed to keyboard/mouse commands) it isn't too bad.

If you're on Windows, I'd probably go with sending Windows messages.

**EDIT**

If your app is a console app, it might be much easier.

If you launch the app  from a C or C++ program you can redirect stdin and stdout to pipes and control the i/o.  You may well be able to do it from Python, but I'm no expert on that.    Check out popen() or CreateFile() (Win only).

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I was hoping that there would be some sort of Python script that I could run perhaps at the same time as the VS app is running, that I could then control the Input into the console. On second thoughts the question is badly phrased.